# ASIFormDataRequest empty POST request

Tags: iphone, ios, nginx, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIFormDataRequest to send multipart POST data to a server running nginx + php-fpm.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:sessionKey forKey:@"session"];
[request setPostValue:secret forKey:@"secret"];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"description"];
[request setFile:filePath forKey:@"image"]; 
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

However, once in a while (occurs very randomly, hard to reproduce) an empty request reaches server, I'm using the same file for all tests. ASIHTTPRequest peforms requestFinished, like everything's ok.

No server-side errors generated, I checked logs.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Updated your ASIHTTPRequest to the latest? Tried manually loading the file then sending the NSData to the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem too earlier today. It has something to do with nginx behaviour on how to reuse a connection. A simple fix is to just add the following to your request procedure:

```
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
```

This option also has been set to NO by default in the newest build of ASIHTTPRequest. Read more about it at Github:

[Stop using persisted connections on POST/PUT](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/issues/94)